# Customising QGIS Map Composer default output directory and file name suffix?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, cartography

I am using QGIS for map making , I am adding multiple vector and raster layers and then finally for map making I am moving to the map composer. When I am exporting the map from Map composer , I want to export it to a particular directory and I want to add a suffix to the filename that user inputs in the Export dialog.

Comment: Please clarify what you need. Do you want to hard-code the export directory so that users can only export to a certain directory?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem with that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OP is looking for a solution that would preselect a save directory and add a suffix to the filename automatically - e.g. YourMap_mysuffix.jpg as a final name.

Comment: As Simbanagu told , I am looking to export the map to predefined directory and suffix to the filename.